# Spring jwt authentication filter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

i'm new to spring security and i'm learn to build restful APIs with JWT.
I searched the internet how to authenticate user on certain end-point but the problem is all end-points requires authentication including the login(which i don't want) even if i permitted it like so.

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityUtility extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationProvider authenticationprovider;
    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint entryPoint;

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() {
        return new ProviderManager(Collections.singletonList(authenticationprovider));
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter authenticationTokenFilter() {
        JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter filter = new JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter();
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
        filter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(new JwtSuccessHandler());
        return filter;
    }

    private static final String[] PUBLIC_MATCHERS = {
            "/login",
            "/logout",
            "/forgot-password"
    };



@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, 
                "/login",
                "/forgot-password"
        );
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {


        http.csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests().antMatchers(PUBLIC_MATCHERS).permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(entryPoint)
        .and()
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        http.headers().cacheControl();
    }
}
```

i guess it's because here below in the constructor it says filter all.

```
    public class JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter  extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter{

    public JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter() {
        super("/**");
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {
        String header = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        if(header== null || !header.startsWith("Token "))
            throw new RuntimeException("Token is missing");

        String authenticationToken = header.substring(6);
        JwtAuthenticationToken token = new JwtAuthenticationToken(authenticationToken);
        return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(token);
    }


    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain,
            Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {
        super.successfulAuthentication(request, response, chain, authResult);
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }


}
```

But when i add like a prefix on the path (like below) it works fine.

```
public JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter() {
    super("/api/**");
}
```

So who can i do this without adding anything before my end-points. so that i can permit some end-point and authenticate the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your SecurityUtility class you can override the `configure(WebSecurity web)` method of the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter class.

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    // JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter will ignore the below paths
    web.ignoring().antMatchers(
            HttpMethod.POST,
            "/api/auth/**"
    );
    web.ignoring().antMatchers(
            HttpMethod.GET,
            "/",
            "/actuator/**",
            "/beer/**",
            "/comment/**",
            "/signIn",
            "/asset-manifest.json",
            "/favicon.ico",
            "/index.html",
            "/service-worker.js",
            "/static/**",
            "/webjars/**",
            "/*.html",
            "/favicon.ico",
            "/**/*.html",
            "/**/*.css",
            "/**/*.js"
    );
}
```

}

Here is an example [MultiWebSecurityConfig.java](https://github.com/TransEmpiric/iso-web-template/blob/master/src/main/java/com/transempiric/webTemplate/config/security/MultiWebSecurityConfig.java)

Comment: thanks for the answer, so i edit my question by adding what you recommended, but it has no effect as i still get the same result. if any other suggest that will be great.

Comment: Hmm... Perhaps the AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter is taking precedence on all request, `/**`. We extended `OncePerRequestFilter`, [TransAuthAuthenticationFilter](https://github.com/TransEmpiric/iso-web-template/blob/master/src/main/java/com/transempiric/transAuth/security/TransAuthAuthenticationFilter.java). Maybe try extending `OncePerRequestFilter`.  Also, if you have not done so, turn on all spring debuging and follow the request, it may provided some clues.

Comment: Seriously look at the code I provided you in the `TransAuth` sub-project.  This is how you write a JWT filter for spring and it is meant to be a simple version of Oauth2, removing complexity not needed by most web-apps.  There is also a live production example, so you know that it works.  It will also work with Webflux.  Love the down votes with no comments, look at the code!  It will be available on Maven Central soon.